# How to do this in mysql: "Select * from $table where varchar_number between numberInString1 and numberString2";

Tags: mysql, numbers, varchar, between

How can I implement something like this in mysql:

```
"SELECT * FROM $database_table 
 WHERE satellite_derived_time 
       BETWEEN '{$from_time}' AND '{$to_time}'";
```

Where `'{$from_time}'` is a number in `varchar` like `"1000"`
     and `'{$to_time}'` is a number in `varchar` too like `"9999"`.

Comment: cast it into an unsigned? CAST('{$from_time}' AS UNSIGNED) AND CAST('{$to_time}' AS UNSIGNED)

Answer (score 1):

try this one-

```
SELECT * FROM $database_table WHERE (satellite_derived_time BETWEEN $from_time AND $to_time);
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not the answer because I think we need to convert varchar to int by CAST UNSIGNED.

Comment: Not really. Because the first one solved my problem. Thanks anyway.